# Compute c > 0 for $f(n)$ = $c*n^{-4}$

Tags: probability-theory

In each of the following cases compute $c$ $>$ $0$ such that $f(n)$ is the pmf of a discrete random variable on {${1,2,...}$}

1) $f(n)$ $=$ $c*n^{-4}$. Here I found: $c$ $=$ $90$/$\pi$$^4$, because I recognized the P-series/

2) $f(n)$ $=$ $c*3^{−n}/n$.

3) $f(n)$ $=$ $c*3^{−n}$. Here I found $c$ $=$ $2$, because I recognized the geometric series.

4) $f(n)$ $=$ $c*4^n/n!$. Here I found $c$ $=$ $e^{-4}$, because I recognized the exponential series.

Any suggestion for solving the second question would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In each case , the function $f$ has the property that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=1.$$

For example we consider 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)= c \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3^{-n}= c (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{-n}-1)=c (\frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{3}}-1)= \frac{c}{2}.$$

Hence: $c=2.$

Comment: Thankyou, for 4 I found that c = 1/e^4. Because I recognized the exponential series. But I still cannot figure out for 1 and 2. For 1, I thought of a P-series

Comment: For 1, I found c = 90/pi^4. I am stuck at question 2.