# Find $c$ for the pmf $f(n)$ = $c$ $*$ $3^{-n}$ $/$ $n$

Tags: probability-theory

I have to compute $c > 0$ such that $f(n)$ = $c$ $*$ $3^{-n}$ $/$ $n$ is the pmf of a discrete random variable on {1,2,...}.

I tried the following, but I am quite sure it is incorrect.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $c$ $*$ $3^{-n}$ $/$ $n$ $=$ $c$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $3^{-n}$ $/$ $n$ $=$ $c$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $3^{-n}$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $1/n$ gives

$c$[$1/3 + 1/9 + 1/27 +...$][$1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +...$]

Where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $3^{-n}$ can be seen as a geometric series and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $1/n$ as a harmonic series

Then we have to solve

$c$ $*$ [$1/3$ /($1-1/3$)] $*$ $\infty$ $=$ $1$ which leads to $c = 0$.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669455/compute-c-0-for-fn-cn-4).

Comment: yeaah I know, I asked that question too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find $c$ it's enough to fing $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^{-n}}{n}$. There is a standard trick to do this: consider function $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(3x)^{-n}}{n}$ (the sum is equal to $f(1)$), find $f'(x)$ by member-wise differentiation (it will be a very simple series), find $f(x)$ as $\int_0^x f'(y)\, dy$ and then find $f(1)$.

For your solution - it looks like you implicitly assumed $\sum_n a_n \cdot b_n = (\sum_n a_n)\cdot(\sum_n b_n)$, which of course isn't true.

Comment: Thankyou, I shall try to solve it this way.